# Configure what counts as a javadoc comment in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Block comments become useless if the documentation is thorough, because a single `*/` is an impenetrable barrier to block comments. I'm told doxygen accepts (or at least can accept) regular `//` comments instead, but netbeans doesn't by default.

Is there a way to configure it to treat all comments as javadocs?

For example:

```
/** javadocs*/
class well_documented
{
   /** javadocs*/
   Variable A;
   /** javadocs*/
   Variable B;
   /** javadocs*/
   Variable C;
   /** javadocs*/
   Variable D;
   //I want to start the block comment here
   /** javadocs*/
   void method aa(){}
   /** javadocs*/
   void method bb(){}
   /** javadocs*/
   void method cc(){}
   /** javadocs*/
   void method dd(){}
   //and end it here.
}
```

I would do this as an alternative to deleting it and worrying about loosing my "undo history", to keep as a handy reference when I'm rewriting these functions, or just as a quick way to test if these methods are ever used (comment out and see if it complains)

Answer (score 0):

I understand now that what you wish for is the possibility to easily comment out blocks of code that contains JavaDoc. For your two different use cases for this, I recommend two different solutions, neither of which involves changing the JavaDoc comment style (which would confuse everyone else who reads your code):

- Quickly (un)comment code during development: Your IDE should have a block comment/uncomment function, which should be able to handle the fact that part of what you're commenting out is a block comment (by using `//` at the start of each line, or by turning `Variable A; /** javadocs */ Variable B;` into `/*Variable A; /** javadocs *//* Variable B;*/` - ugly, but it's only temporary, and the IDE should be able to uncomment it back to the original state).
- Keeping for later reference: *Please don't do this!* Over time, your codebase will accumulate masses of such commented-out code and become unreadable. The correct solution here is to take advantage of your source control system (if you don't have one, *make it your department's number one priority to start using source control*): if it was ever committed, it will remain in your history forever even if you delete it, and it can be revived if you ever need it. If it's code from a new, uncommitted experiment, use the stash/shelve functionality of your source control system, or create a separate branch to keep track of it; commit it there and then go back to before you introduced the code.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I mean using a single line comment `//javadocs` instead of a block comment `/** javadocs*/` because I want to avoid the `*/` that makes all surrounding block comments a tedious mess.

Comment: ...are you putting JavaDoc comments inside regular block comments? If not, what is the problem with having
`/* Block comment */` (newline) `/** JavaDoc */` (newline) `/* Block comment */`?

Comment: (It would help if you posted an example of code you feel becomes tedious because of the `*/`)

Comment: I updated my question to include an example. If I wanted to start a comment and end the comment where I indicated, I'd have to write `/*` or `*/` at least 8 times, basically defeating the whole point of a block comment.

Comment: Thanks; that made your intent much clearer. See my updated answer. Also, please read the first two answers to [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), since I would claim that your question (how to make JavaDoc accept `//`) isn't really about your actual problem (how to block comment something that already contains block comments, or how to keep "inactive" code for future reference).

Comment: The only other person who'll ever see the code is a team mate who doesn't use an IDE. Its not so much "keeping for later reference" as "keeping until the replacement is satisfactory" or "keeping until I decide the replacement isn't viable" or "keeping it for swapping out for purposes of comparison".  Its all about working around the fact that `/* */` doesn't nest like `{ }`.  Is there a way to do short descriptions with `@` tags?

Comment: I see - not to my knowledge, though. I'd suggest that your teammate gets an IDE or at least an editor that is powerful enough to perform block commenting or can be programmed with a macro or plugin to do it. Surely, NetBeans can do this more smartly than just wrapping your selection with `/* */`?

Comment: By default Netbeans puts `//` at the beginning of every line in the selected area which is super tedious to remove manually. I'm glad it doesn't do block comments as you described in your first comment above, because netbeans wouldn't know which ones to when uncommenting.

Comment: Isn't there an "uncomment" function? If not, did you try using "comment" or "toggle comment" on a `//`-commented section? That might remove the comments again. Many editors also have a block select: Alt+click-and-drag. Alternatively, switch to IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse...

Comment: Final result: notepad++ (which other team member uses) can handle mass commenting and uncommenting of lines with `//` at the beginning and block comments are dead to us now, except for purposes of javadocing.

Comment: I'm still surprised that your tools don't support block comments better, but if this solution floats your boat, go for it. One question, though: are you using source control?

Comment: Yes, but we mostly use it as a third party backup and sharing method, I don't think we've ever reverted and only really use past revs to find what has changed since last time we looked at the others code.

Comment: I strongly recommend learning the full feature set of your source control system and to use it as a more central part of your daily work; it can be a major timesaver (and sometimes a lifesaver). I never hesitate to tentatively delete anything from our codebase; seeing what was deleted is as simple as `git diff`, and getting it back is `git checkout`.